# Future Value of yearly investments

Tags: python

Suppose you have an investment plan where you invest a certain fixed amount at the beginning of every year. Compute the total value of the investment at the end of the last year. The inputs will be the amount to invest each year, the interest rate, and the number of years of the investment.

This program calculates the future value
of a constant yearly investment.
Enter the yearly investment: 200
Enter the annual interest rate: .06
Enter the number of years: 12
The value in 12 years is: 3576.427533818945

I've tried a few different things, like below, but it doesn't give me that 3576.42, it gives me only $400. Any ideas?

```
principal = eval(input("Enter the yearly investment: "))
apr = eval(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))
years = eval(input("Enter the number of years: "))
for i in range(years):
    principal = principal * (1+apr)
print("The value in 12 years is: ", principal)
```

Comment: Who's idea is it to use `eval` instead of `float`? plunk!

Comment: @gnibbler +1 for pointing that out.  Off-topic pet peeve: you mean *whose*, not *who's*.

Comment: @DarshanComputing, Of course. You must hate [HTTP_referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) too :)

Comment: @DarshanComputing, I really hope `eval` wasn't used by the teacher in `futval.py`

Comment: @gnibbler It's unpleasant to look at, but at least it makes for an interesting bit of computer history ;)  And I'd certainly hope no teachers are demonstrating that kind of misuse of `eval`!

Comment: [Python - Zelle book uses eval(), is it wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995787/python-zelle-book-uses-eval-is-it-wrong/15995875#15995875)

Comment: I'm guessing the `eval` resulted from `2to3` tool automatic porting of 2.x code using `input`. :/

Answer (score 2):

If it's a yearly investment, you should add it every year:

```
yearly = float(input("Enter the yearly investment: "))
apr = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))
years = int(input("Enter the number of years: "))

total = 0
for i in range(years):
    total += yearly
    total *= 1 + apr

print("The value in 12 years is: ", total)
```

With your inputs, this outputs

```
('The value in 12 years is: ', 3576.427533818945)
```

**Update:** Responding to your questions from the comments, to clarify what's going on:

1) You can use `int()` for `yearly` and get the same answer,  which is fine if you always invest a whole number of currency.  Using a float works just as well but also allows the amount to be `199.99`, for example.

2) `+=` and `*=` are convenient shorthand: `total += yearly` means `total = total + yearly`.  It's a little easier to type, but more important, it more clearly expresses the meaning.  I read it like this

```
for i in range(years): # For each year
    total += yearly    # Grow the total by adding the yearly investment to it
    total *= 1 + apr   # Grow the total by multiplying it by (1 + apr)
```

The longer form just isn't as clear:

```
for i in range(years):        # For each year
    total = total + yearly    # Add total and yearly and assign that to total
    total = total * (1 + apr) # Multiply total by (1 + apr) and assign that to total
```

Comment: This fatals, `years` has to be `int()`

Comment: @mdierker Thanks, I actually fixed that prior to your comment.  I posted before running it, and there must have been a delay before SO showed you my edits.

Comment: Hi Darshan, your program does give me the correct answer, but would you mind walking me through it, so I can recreate this program solely off the knowledge I gain? So, some quick questions if you don't mind. How come eval wouldn't be proper here? Eval gives me the correct answer as well. Also, I believe that floats are used when you're using decimals, but how come there must be a float after "yearly"? I understand for apr, you'd need float for the %. Also, what does "total += yearly" simply means "total = total + yearly". Just a shortcut way of writing it I suppose?

Comment: @user2293767 I just updated my answer to answer your initial questions. I see you just changed your comment a bit; I think the only thing really new is asking for clarification about `eval()`. Honestly, for your purposes, there's no real harm in using it; it's just considered bad practice in general, and it seems like a good idea to learn best practices from the beginning. The main issue is that `eval()` will run whatever it's given as code, so someone could type something nasty instead of typing the numbers you asked for. There are countless more in-depth explanations available elsewhere.

Comment: I appreciate the insight! Also, in response to "The main issue is that eval() will run whatever it's given as code, so someone could type something nasty instead of typing the numbers you asked for." I gave this a shot, and had the user input something other than a number, but it actually returned an error. The textbook itself says that eval "should" be used when the user input is expected to be a number. Mind clearing this up? And, about starting off the "total=0" what is this practice called? Is this common? I think something to do with something about accumulator I believe?

Comment: If you really want to understand `eval()`, search the web or look at all the questions here on SO about it.  I wrote my code with `float()` and `int()` because I think that's better practice, but your question was about getting an unexpected result, and I showed you where you went wrong. The rest is feeling off topic.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done analytically:

```html
"""
pmt = investment per period
r = interest rate per period
n = number of periods
v0 = initial value
"""
fv = lambda pmt, r, n, v0=0: pmt * ((1.0+r)**n-1)/r + v0*(1+r)**n
fv(200, 0.09, 10, 2000)
```

Similarly, if you are trying to figure out the amount you need to invest so you get to a certain number, you can do:

```html
pmt = lambda fv, r, n, v0=0: (fv - v0*(1+r)**n) * r/((1.0+r)**n-1) 
pmt(1000000, 0.09, 20, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you shouldn't use `eval()` here. (More info on eval can be found [in the Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)). -- Instead, change your code to use `float()` or `int()` where applicable, as shown below.

Also, your `print()` statement printed out the parenthesis and comma, which I expect you didn't want. I cleaned it up in the code below, but if what you wanted is what you had feel free to put it back.

```
principal = float(input("Enter the yearly investment: "))
apr = float(input("Enter the annual interest rate: "))

# Note that years has to be int() because of range()
years = int(input("Enter the number of years: "))

for i in range(years):
    principal = principal * (1+apr)
print "The value in 12 years is: %f" % principal
```