# Iterate through list of intervals in Python and return odd and even values?

Tags: python, list, loops, python-3.x

I'm working on a fragment of code for a homework assignment.

I want to:

1. Get user input(n).
2. Make a list out of the input(n) range.
3. Iterate through the list.
4. Count Odds and Evens.
5. Return Odds and Evens for use in another function

I am stumped and this is as far as I got:

```
def Input():
    n = eval(input("Enter number: "))

def GetOdds(n):
    odd_count = 0
    even_count = 0
    List_start = List[1]
    List_cont = List[1:]

    for i in range(n):
        ## I know I'll be using something like ## 
                if position % 2 == 0:
                                even_count = even_count+1
    return even_count
    return odd_count
```

Comment: There's no need for `eval`; just `int` suffices and is much safer. But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @larsmans I'm guessing Zelle book, you don't want to get [this argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995787/python-zelle-book-uses-eval-is-it-wrong) started again... Just to be clear I do agree with you.

Comment: @jamylak: thanks for the link, hadn't seen that question. Interesting discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like:

```
def GetOddEvenCount(n):
    odd_count = 0
    even_count = 0

    for elem in range(n):
        if elem % 2 == 0: even_count += 1
        else: odd_count += 1
    return odd_count, even_count
```

Example usage :

```
odd_count, even_count = GetOddEvenCount(10)
print("Odds:", odd_count, "Evens:", even_count)
```

Outputs:

```
Odds: 5 Evens: 5
```

Note however, that if you're only returning the *counts*, and not a list of the actual odd/even values, then the return value of this function can be computed trivially in O(1) time by taking advantage of the fact that for any **even** integer N, the return value will always be `(N/2, N/2)`, and for any **odd** integer N, the return value will always be `(floor(N/2), floor(N/2) + 1)`

Comment: If you do `N/2.0` or work in Python3, you could even return `(int(floor(N/2.0)), int(ceil(N/2.0)))` in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a dictionary to get all the odd numbers as well:

```
def GetOdds(n):
    d = {'Odds':[],'Evens':[], 'Odd_count':0,'Even_count':0}
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            d['Evens'].append(i)
            d['Even_count'] += 1
        else:
            d['Odds'].append(i)
            d['Odd_count'] += 1
    return d
```

As an example:

```
>>> GetOdds(int(input('Enter a number '))) # Let's do 10 for example
{'Odds': [1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 'Evens': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], 'Odd_count': 5, 'Even_count': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple values in your `return` statement. e.g.

```
def func():
    return 1,2

x, y = func()
```

In that case, the function will assign `x = 1` and `y = 2`

So in your case make your `return` statement

```
return even_count, odd_count
```

and when you call the function use

```
even, odd = GetOdds(16)
```

And for your odd-even differentiation your `if` statement is correct, you just need to add an `else` clause for odd numbers and change `position` to `i` (or vise-versa)

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    even_count = even_count+1
else:
    odd_count = odd_count+1
```